# Fluid width HTML5 Video not working on iPad or iPhone?

Tags: css, html, video, fluid-layout

Hi there I have some videos that when viewed on my desktop are sizing down responsively.

I'm using…

```
video {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Which as I say works perfectly if you scale the browser down on my desktop. However when I view this on an iPad or iPhone the videos aren't scaling down as they should.

I read that you need the height and width to be specified for the video to display properly on these devices however if I do so they will no longer be fluid.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="videoWrapper">  
        <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
        <iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

    .videoWrapper {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
            padding-top: 25px;
            height: 0;
    }
    .videoWrapper iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
}
```